# Prob. 10, Sec. 16 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Comparison amongst the product, dictionary, and subspace topologies on $I \times I$, where $I = [0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

Here is Prob. 10, Sec. 16 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $I = [0, 1]$. Compare the product topology on $I \times I$, the dictionary order topology on $I \times I$, and the topology $I \times I$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ in the dictionary order topology.

My Effort:

> The order topology on $I = [0, 1]$ has as a basis all sets of the following three types:
>
> (i) all the half open intervals $[0, b)$, where $b$ is a real number such that $0 < b \leq 1$
>
> (ii) all the open intervals $(a, b)$, where $a, b \in I$ such that $a < b$.
>
> (iii) all the half-open intervals $(a,1]$, where $a$ is a real number such that $0 \leq a < 1$
>
> So the product topology on $I \times I$ has as a basis all the Cartesian products of all possible sets of the above three types.
>
> The dictionary order topology on $I \times I$ has as a basis all sets of the following three types:
>
> (i) all sets of the form $$\left[ 0 \times 0, a \times b \right) \colon= \left\{ \ x \times y \in I \times I \ \colon \ 0 \times 0 \preceq x\times y \prec a \times b \ \right\}, $$
>   where $a \times b \in I$ such that $0 \times 0 \prec a \times b$ and $\prec$ denotes the dictionary order on $I \times I$; that is, for any points $x_1 \times y_1, x_2 \times y_2 \in I \times I$, we define $x_1 \times y_1 \prec x_2 \times y_2$ to mean that either (i) $x_1 < x_2$, or (ii) $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$. Here $<$ denotes the usual order on the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers.
>
> (ii) all sets of the form $$ \left( a \times b, 1 \times 1 \right] \colon= \left\{ \ x \times y \in I \times I \ \colon \ a \times b \prec x \times y \preceq 1 \times 1 \ \right\}, $$ where $a \times b \in I \times I$ such that $a \times b \prec 1$
>
> (iii) all sets of the form $$ \left( a \times b, c \times d  \right) \colon= \left\{ \ x \times y \in I \times I \ \colon \  a \times b \prec x \times y  \prec c \times d   \ \right\}, $$ where $a \times b \in I \times I$ and $c \times d \in I \times I$ such that $a \times b \prec c \times d$
>
> The dictionary order topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ has as a basis all sets of the form $$ \left\{ a \right\} \times (b, c) \colon= \left\{ \ a \times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ b < y < c \ \right\}, \tag{1} $$
>   where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real numbers such that $b < c$.
>
> So, the subspace topology inherited by $I \times I$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ in the dictionary order topology has as a basis all sets that are the intersections with $I \times I$ of sets of the form in (1) above. that is, all sets of the form 
>    $$ \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ a \right\} \times (b, c) \ \right],$$ 
>   where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real numbers such that $b < c$.

Am I right so far?

Now for the comparisons!

Product vs. Dictionary Order:

> The set $$[0, 1/2) \times ( 1/2, 1] \colon= \left\{ \ x \times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ 0 \leq x < 1/2, \ 1/2 < y \leq 1 \ \right\} $$ is open in the product topology on $I \times I$, but it is not open in the dictionary order topology on $I \times I$, because this set contains the point $0 \times 1$ and if 
>   $$\left( 0 \times b, c \times d \right) = \left\{ \ x \times y  \in I \times I \ \colon \ 0 \times b \prec x \times y \prec c \times d \ \right\}$$ is a dictionary order topology basis element containing $0 \times 1$, then 
>   $$0 \times b \prec 0 \times 1 \prec c \times d.$$
>   Therefore $$ b < 1 \ \mbox{ and } \ 0 < c.$$ 
>   Then $$ c/2 \times 1/3 \in \left[ \ \left( 0 \times b, c \times d \right) \ \right] \setminus \left[ \ [0, 1/2) \times ( 1/2, 1]  \  \right], $$
>   which shows that $$ \left( 0 \times b, c \times d \right) \not\subset  [0, 1/2) \times ( 1/2, 1].$$
>
> Thus the dictionary order topology on $I \times I$ is not finer than the product topology.

Am I right?

> The set 
>   $$ \left\{ 0 \right\} \times [0, 1/2) = \left[ 0 \times 0, 0 \times 1/2 \right) = \left\{ \ x \times y \in I \times I \ \colon \ 0 \times 0 \preceq x \times y \prec 0 \times 1/2 \ \right\}$$ is open in the dictionary order topology on $I \times I$ but not open in the product topology, because this set contains the point $0 \times 0$ but if 
>   $$[0, b) \times [0, d) = \left\{ \ x \times y \in I \times I \ \colon \ 0 \leq x < b, \ 0 \leq y < d \ \right\}$$ is a basis element for the product topology on $I \times I$ containing $0 \times 0$, then we must have 
>   $$ 0 < b \mbox{ and } 0 < d,$$
>   which implies that 
>   $$ b/2 \times d/2 \in \left[ \ [0, b) \times [0, d) \ \right] \setminus \left[ \ \left\{ 0 \right\} \times [0, 1/2)  \ \right],$$
>   which shows that $$ [0, b) \times [0, d) \not\subset \left\{ 0 \right\} \times [0, 1/2).$$
>
> Thus the product topology on $I \times I$ is not finer than the dictionary order topology.

Am I right?

> Therefore, the product topology and the dictionary order topology on $I \times I$ are not comparable.

Have I arrived at the correct conclusion? And if so, then using correct logic?

Product vs. Subspace:

> The set $$\left\{ 0 \right\} \times \left( 1/2, 1 \right] = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ 0 \right\} \times \left( 1/2, 3/2 \right] \ \right]$$ is open in the subspace topology but not open in the product topology, because this set contains the point $0 \times 1$, but any product-topology basis containing $0 \times 1$ must be of the form
>   $$[0, a) \times (b, 1] = \left\{ \ x \times y \in I \times I \ \colon \ 0 \leq x < a, \ b < y \leq 1 \ \right\}$$ for some elements $a, b \in I$ such that $a > 0$ and $b < 1$, and 
>   $$ a/2 \times 1 \in \left[ \ [0, a) \times (b, 1] \ \right] \setminus \left[ \ \left\{ 0 \right\} \times \left( 1/2, 1 \right]  \ \right],$$
>   which shows that 
>   $$ [0, a) \times (b, 1] \not\subset \left\{ 0 \right\} \times \left( 1/2, 1 \right]. $$
>
> Thus the product topolgy on $I \times I$ is not finer than the subspace topology $I \times I$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ in the dictionary order topology.

Am I right?

> Now let $B$ be a product topology basis element, and let $x \times y \in B$.
>
> If 
>   $$ B = [0, a) \times [0, b) = \left\{ \ x \times y \in I \times I \ \colon \ 0 \leq x < a, \ 0 \leq y < b \ \right\},$$
>   where $a, b \in I$ such that $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, then $0 \leq x < a$ and $0 \leq y < b$. So the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$\left\{ x \right\} \times \left[0, (b+y)/2 \right)= \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left(-1/2, (b+y)/2 \right) \ \right] $$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $[0, a) \times [0, b)$.

Am I right?

> If $B= [0, a) \times (b, c)$, where $a, b, c \in I$ such that $a > 0$ and $b < c$, then $0 \leq x < a$ and $b < y < c$, and so the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times (b, c) = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times (b, c) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> If $B = [0, a) \times (b, 1]$, where $a, b \in I$ such that $a > 0$ and $b < 1$, then $0 \leq x < a$ and $b < y \leq 1$, and the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left( (b+y)/2, 1 \right] = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left( (b+y)/2, 3/2 \right)  \ \right] $$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> If $B = (a, b) \times [0, c)$, where $a, b, c \in I$ such that $a < b$ and $0 < c$, then $a < x < b$ and $0 \leq y < c$. So the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left[0, (y+c)/2 \right) = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left(-1/2, (y+c)/2 \right) \ \right] $$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> If $B = (a, b) \times (c, d)$, where $a, b, c, d \in I$ such that $a < b$ and $c < d$, then we have $a < x < b$ and $c < y < d$. So the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times (c, d) = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \  \left\{ x \right\} \times (c, d) \ \right]$$ 
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> If $B = (a, b) \times (c, 1]$, where $a, b, c, \in I$ such that $a < b$ and $c < 1$, then we have $a < x < b$ and $c < y \leq 1$. So the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left( (c+y)/2, 1 \right] = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left( (c+y)/2, 3/2 \right)  \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> If $B = (a, 1] \times [0, b)$, where $a, b \in I$ such that $a < 1$ and $b > 0$, then we have $a < x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y < b$. So the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left[ 0, (y+b)/2 \right) = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left( -1 , (y+b)/2 \right) \ \right]$$ 
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am i right?

> If $B = (a, 1] \times (b, c)$, where $a, b, c \in I$ such that $a < 1$ and $b < c$, then we have $a < x \leq 1$ and $b < y < c$. So the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times (b, c) = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \  \left\{ x \right\} \times (b, c) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Finally, if $B = (a, 1] \times (b, 1]$, where $a, b \in I$ such that $a < 1$ and $b < 1$, then we have $a < x \leq 1$ and $b < y \leq 1$. So the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left( (b+y)/2, 1 \right] = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times \left( (b+y)/2, 3/2 \right) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.
>
> Thus, in each of the nine possiblities for $B$, we can find a subspace topology basis element $B^\prime$ such that $$ x \times y \in B^\prime \subset B.$$
>
> Hence the subspace topology on $I \times I$ is strictly finer than the product topology.

Am I right?

Subspace vs. Dictionary Order:

> The set $$\left\{ 0 \right\} \times \left( 1/2, 1 \right] = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[  \{ 0 \} \times ( 1/2, 3/2 )  \right] $$
>   is open in the subspace topology but not open in the dictionary order topology. If $\left( a \times b, c \times d \right)$ is a dictionary order topology basis element containing $0 \times 1$, where $a, b, c, d \in I$ such that $a \times b \prec c \times d$, that is, such that, either $a < c$ or $a = c$ and $b < d$, then 
>   $$ a \times b \prec 0 \times 1 \prec c \times d,$$
>   which implies that 
>   $$ a = 0, \ b<1, \ \mbox{ and } \  0 < c. $$
>   Thus our dictionary order topology basis element containing $0 \times 1$ is of the form 
>   $$ \left( 0 \times b, c \times d \right),$$
>   where $0 \leq b < 1$ and $0 < c \leq 1$, and of course $0 \leq d \leq 1$.
>
> Thus we see that 
>   $$ \frac{c}{2}  \times 0  \in \left[ \  \left( 0 \times b, c \times d \right) \ \right] 
> \setminus \left[ \ \left\{ 0 \right\} \times \left( 1/2, 1 \right] \ \right],$$
>   which shows that 
>   $$ \left( 0 \times b, c \times d \right) \not\subset \left\{ 0 \right\} \times \left( 1/2, 1 \right].$$
>
> Thus the dictionary order topology is not finer than the subspace topology.

Am I right?

> Now let $B$ be a dictionary order topology basis element, and let $x \times y \in B$.
>
> If $B = \left[ 0 \times 0, a \times b \right)$, where $a, b \in I$ such that $0 \times 0 \prec a \times b$, that is, such that, either
>   $0 < a$, or $0 = a$ and $0 < b$, then we have 
>   $$ 0 \times 0 \prec x \times y \prec a \times b,$$
>   that is, exactly one of the following four cases holds.
>
> (i) $0 < x < a$ and $y, b \in I$ are arbitrary
>
> (ii) $0 = x < a$ and $0 < y$
>
> (iii) $0 < x = a$ and $ y < b$
>
> (iv) $0 = x = a$ and $0 < y < b$

Am I right?

> Case (i) If $0 < x < a$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times I = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times (-2, 2) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Case (ii) If $0 = x < a$ and $0 < y$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ 0 \right\} \times \left( y / 2, 1 \right] = \left( I \times I \right) \cap 
> \left[ \  \left\{ 0 \right\} \times \left( y / 2, 2 \right) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Case (iii) If $0 < x = a$ and $y < b$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ a \right\} \times \left[ 0, b \right) = \left( I \times I \right) 
> \cap \left[ \  \left\{ a \right\} \times \left(-1, b \right) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Case (iv) If $0 = x = a$ and $0 < y < b$, then the subspace topology basis element
>   $$ \left\{ 0 \right\} \times (0, b) = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ 0 \right\} \times (0, b)\ \right]$$ 
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> If $B = \left( a \times b, 1 \times 1 \right]$, where 
>   $a \times b \in I \times I$ such that $ a \times b \prec 1 \times 1$, 
>   then 
>   $$a \times b \prec  x \times y \prec 1 \times 1,$$
>   and the following are all the possible cases.
>
> (i) $a < x < 1$ and $y, b \in I$ are arbitrary
>
> (ii) $a = x < 1$ and $b < y$
>
> (iii) $a < x = 1$ and $y < 1$
>
> (iv) $a = x = 1$ and $b < y < 1$

Am I right?

> Case (i) If $a < x < 1$, then the subspace topology basis element
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times I = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times (-2, 2) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Case (ii) If $a = x < 1$ and $b < y$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ a \right\} \times (b, 1 ] = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ a \right\} \times (b, 2) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Case (iii) If $a < x = 1$ and $y < 1$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ 1 \right\} \times \left[ 0, (y+1)/2 \right) = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ 1 \right\} \times \left( -1, (y+1)/2 \right) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Case (iv) If $a = x = 1$ and $b < y < 1$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ 1 \right\} \times (b, 1) = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \  \left\{ 1 \right\} \times (b, 1) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Finally, if $B = \left( a \times b, c \times d \right)$, where $a \times b \in I \times I$ and $c \times d \in I \times I$ such that $a \times b \prec c \times d$, then we have 
>   $$ a \times b \prec x \times y \prec c \times d,$$
>   and the following cases arise.
>
> (i) $a < x < c$ and $b, y, d \in I$ are arbitrary
>
> (ii) $a = x < c$ and $b < y$
>
> (iii) $a < x = c$ and $y < d$
>
> (iv) $a = x = c$ and $b < y < d$

Am I right?

> Case (i) If $a < x < c$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times I = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times (-2, 2) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Case (ii) If $a = x < c$ and $b < y$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times (b, 1] = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times (b, 2) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Case (iii) If $a < x = c$ and $y < d$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times [0, d)  = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times (-1, d) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Case (iv) If $a = x = c$ and $b < y < d$, then the subspace topology basis element 
>   $$ \left\{ x \right\} \times (b, d)  = \left( I \times I \right) \cap \left[ \ \left\{ x \right\} \times (b, d) \ \right]$$
>   contains $x \times y$ and is contained in $B$.

Am I right?

> Thus in all possible cases, we have shown that for any dictionary order topology basis element $B$ and for any element $x \times y \in B$, there exists a subspace topology basis element $B^\prime$ such that 
>   $$ x \times y \in B^\prime \subset B.$$
>
> Thus the subspace topology on $I \times I$ is strictly finer than the dictionary order topology.

Am I right?

> Now to recap, the subspace topology that  $I \times I$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is strictly finer than both the product topology and the dictionary order topology on $I \times I$, whereas these two topologies are not comparable.

Have i arrived at the correct conclusion?

If so, is my reasoning error-free?

If not, then where have I gone wrong?

Comment: https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-2/section-16-the-subspace-topology/problem-10-solution seems to agree with you.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma and what about you? Can you please take time reading carefuly through my post and then advise me if there're any mistakes?

Comment: You seem to want to case distinguish everything, it's a bit tiring. Maybe work with subbase elements, there are only two types (in both the product and the order topology).

Comment: I corrected a few typos.

Comment: You can also use that the product topology equals the subspace topology w.r.t. to the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. So its basic elements are of the form $(a, b) \times (c,d) \cap (I \times I)$. And these are clearly open in the topology $\mathcal{T}_d \times \mathbb{R}_{\text{euclid}$ relativised to $I \times I$ which is the relativised lexicographic order topology on the plane.

Comment: So $\mathcal{T}_e$ (Euclidean) is a subset of $\mathbb{T}_d$ (discrete) so $ \mathcal{T}_e \times \mathcal{T}_e \subset \mathcal{T}_d \times \mathcal{T}_e$, and the first relative to $I \times I$ is precisely the product topology on $I \times I$ and so we have the easy inclusion that the product topology is contained in the subspace topology. As the strictness can be witnessed on $I \times I$ this inclusion is strict (e.g. $\{\frac{1}{2} \times I$ is open in the subspace topology but not in the product topology on the plane relative to $I \times I$. (e.g. projections are open).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma so nice of you!!

Comment: sir ,, i got its